# Python. Pandas вместо графика пишет координаты

Tags: python, pandas

При построения графика Pandas выдаёт в консоле координаты а не сам график : `AxesSubplot(0.125,0.11;0.775x0.77)` у меня была такая проблема в matplotlib и она решилась тем что я установил matplotlib в папку Scripts. Проделал тоже самое с Pandas но ничего не изменилось.

То что я делаю:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

#Удаляем пустые значения в таблице
df = df.dropna()

#Задаём другой тип данных нужным признакам
df['User_Score'] = df.User_Score.astype('float64')
df['Year_of_Release'] = df.Year_of_Release.astype('int64')
df['User_Count'] = df.User_Count.astype('int64')
df['Critic_Count'] = df.Critic_Count.astype('int64')

#берём те признаки которыми будем пользоваться
useful_cols = ['Name', 'Platform', 'Year_of_Release', 'Genre', 
               'Global_Sales', 'Critic_Score', 'Critic_Count',
               'User_Score', 'User_Count', 'Rating'
              ]

#построим график продаж видео игр в различных странах в зависимости от года. 
#Для начала отфильтруем только нужные нам столбцы, затем посчитаем суммарные 
#продажи по годам и у получившегося DataFrame вызовем функцию plot без 
#параметров

sales_df = df[[x for x in df.columns if 'Sales' in x] + ['Year_of_Release']]
print(sales_df.groupby('Year_of_Release').sum().plot())
```

В итоге получаю: `AxesSubplot(0.125,0.11;0.775x0.77)`  а должен быть график
[Ссылка](https://yadi.sk/i/tEnLXsFt-YViWw) на файл CSV

Comment: Зачем `print` в последней строке?

Comment: Как вы запускаете этот код - как скрипт или из под какого-то IDE (Jupyter/iPython/PyCharm/etc.)?

Comment: Из Sublime text

Comment: Прошу меня извинить. Всего то нужно было `sales_df.groupby('Year_of_Release').sum().plot()
plt.show()`